# How can one show that the hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = x^{p} + \frac{1}{4}$ has only one positive rational solution for every prime $p>3$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Without applying Fermat's Last Theorem, how can one show that the hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = x^{p} + \frac{1}{4}$ has only one positive rational solution $(x,y) = (0, \frac{1}{2})$ for ever prime $p \geq 5$ ?

Comment: May you kindly forgive me for the use of the ''real analysis'' tag. Since i'm quite new on this platform, my rating is not yet sufficient for me to use the number theory, Diophantine analysis or algebraic number theory tags. Thank you.

Comment: Observe that by factoring $y^2 - \frac{1}{4} = (y-\frac{1}{2})(y + \frac{1}{2} )= x^p$, it follows that $y-\frac{1}{2} = u^p$ and $y + \frac{1}{2} = v^p$ hence $v^p - u^p =1$. By FLT we know that this has only one rational solution $(u, v) = (0,1)$ hence in the original question $(x, y) = (0, \frac{1}{2})$. But is there any other way to arrive at this result apart from this one, maybe via the theory of (hyper)elliptic curves ?

Comment: Surprisingly, someone chose to downvote this question, which is way within the rules of MO.

Comment: I have added the tags. But normally you should have been able to do it, AFAIK all tags can be chosen freely, up to 5.

Comment: Thanks Wolfhang, but how does the ''AFAIK'' work ? I have never came across it before ?

Comment: "as far as I know" :)

Comment: You mean non-negative, not positive.

Comment: By the way, when you say that $(y-1/2)(y+1/2)=x^p$ implies $y-1/2=u^p$, $y+1/2=v^p$, you implicitely use that $p$ is odd (if $y-1/2=A/M,y+1/2=(A+M)/M$ for coprime $A$, $M$, then $M^2$ is a perfect $p$-th power, $M$ is itself a $p$-th power, and so are coprime numbers $A$, $A+M$).

Comment: I think it's reasonable to downvote someone who asks a question which they know to be equivalent to FLT and then ask for a proof which doesn't use FLT.

Comment: @eric they probably have not known that it is equivalent while asking question, only implication (from FLT to this fact).

Comment: Doing this without applying FLT would give another proof of FLT. If that had been done, it would very likely be well-known.

Comment: @Fedor: the direction that you suggest might not be known to the OP is far easier than the one they told us they knew :-) Furthermore, neither implication is at the level of this site. This is definitely stackexchange material.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is equivalent to FLT. Indeed, if $a^p+1=b^p$ for positive rational $a,b$, we have $x^p:=(ab)^p=a^p(a^p+1)=(a^p+1/2)^2-1/4:=y^2-1/4$.

Opposite implication (moving from the comments): if $x^p=y^2-1/4=(y-1/2)(y+1/2)$, $x\ne 0$, denote $y-1/2=a/m$ for coprime non-zero integers $a,m$. Then also $a+m\ne 0$, $y+1/2=(a+m)/m$ and $x^p=a(a+m)/m^2$. Since $a,a+m,m$ are mutually coprime and $p$ is odd, we get that they should be all perfect $p$-th powers, $a=A^p$, $m=B^p$, $a+m=C^p$, $A^p+B^p=C^p$.

Comment: You don't need $p$ to be prime?

Comment: I do not, but it is given by OP.

Comment: You mean equivalent to the prime case of FLT.

Comment: Well, FLT is a priori equivalent to its prime case.

Comment: How is this equivalent? FLT implies implies lack of points of the special form $y=(a^p+1/2)$. How does FLT implies lack of points with $y$ not of this form?

Comment: @joro see comments above to the post

Comment: Do you mean this $y^2 - \frac{1}{4} = (y-\frac{1}{2})(y + \frac{1}{2} )= x^p$...?

Comment: @joro yes, I edit the answer for completeness.

Comment: "denote y−1/2=a/m for coprime **positive** integers a,m": this is not possible if $y < 1/2$.

Comment: @joro Ok, fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32564/discussion-between-fedor-petrov-and-joro).

Comment: I am in chat...