# Rational perfect power values of $y(y+1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, hyperelliptic-curves

This is hard, so I am looking for partial results and how hard it is.

Let $n>4$. Is it true that the hyperelliptic curve $x^n=y(y+1)$
doesn't have rational point with $x \ne 0$?

If necessarily assume $n$ is prime.

Integral points on the curve are heavily studied.

It is one of the simplest exponential diophantine equations over the
rationals.

What tools are used for solving it?

FLT implies there are no solutions with $y$ being $n$-th power.

**Added** No solution for given $n$ imply Fermat Last Theorem for $n$ as discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309091/hyperelliptic-curves-imply-flt-like-results) see (3) with a=1

Assume $u^n-v^n=1$ is counterexample to FLT. Then $(uv)^n=v^n(v^n+1)$ and $(uv,v^n)$ is non trivial rational point on the curve.

Comment: Is not this all discussed here? https://mathoverflow.net/q/225324/4312

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think the curves are the same, but the questions are different.

Comment: Is not it the same question - to prove that there are only trivial rational points?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I am asking about tools and partial results.

Comment: It is essentially equivalent to FLT, so this is equivalent to the tools of studying FLT.

Comment: @FedorPetrov The Fermat curve $x^n+y^n=1$ is not isomorphic to the hyperelliptic curve. For n=5 the computer easily solved the hyperelliptic curve and I don't think there is very simple proof on the Fermat curve.

Comment: What do you mean by "computer easily solved"? Any solution gives a solution of FLT for the same exponent, right?

Comment: The computer showed no solutions. Does the equivalence hold over number fields? I well might be missing something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no such solutions. Let $x=a/b$ and $y=c/d$ be reduced fractions. Then 
$a^n/b^n=(c(c+d))/d^2$ and since both sides are reduced fractions we get that
$a^n=c(c+d)$ and $b^n=d^2$. From the first equation we deduce that $c=e^n$ and $c+d=f^n$ since $c$ and $c+d$ are co-prime and their product is an $n$-th power. 
Then $d=f^n-e^n$ so $(f^n-e^n)^2=b^n$. 
If $n$ is even write $n=2k$ and take square root to get $f^{2k}-e^{2k}=\pm b^k$. 
If the sign is $+$ then we get $f^{2k}=e^{2k}+b^k$ and since $k>2$ this implies by FLT that one of $e,b,f$ is 0. If $f=0$ then $y=-1$ so $x=0$. $b=0$ is certainly impossible. Finally, $e=0$ means $y=0$. So this option is excluded.
If the sign is $-$ we get $e^{2k}=f^{2k}+b^k$ and the same reasoning works.

If $n$ is odd, from $(f^n-e^n)^2=b^n$ we deduce that $b$ is a square so $b=g^2$ and then we can extract the root to get $f^n-e^n= \pm g^n$ and proceed in a way similar to the case where $n$ is even.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think proof without FLT/modularity is possible? I have some partial results: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332386/elementary-constraints-for-the-solutions-of-zn-2yyz-xn