# Elementary constraints for the solutions of $z^{n-2}y(y+z)=x^n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, hyperelliptic-curves

Related to FLT and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309162/rational-perfect-power-values-of-yy1).

For natural $n > 4 $ define the curve $C_n : z^{n-2}y(y+z)=x^n$.

$C_n$ has the trivial points with $x=0$ for all $n$.

The answer in the linked question shows there are no other solutions
using FLT.

I am interested in elementary approach without using FLT or
modularity.

> Q1 Do we get constraints or lack of non-trivial coprime 
>   integral points $(X,Y,Z)$ on $C_n$ via elementary approach
>   not using modularity?

Partial results, could be wrong.
Assume $(X,Y,Z)$ is coprime point.

If prime $p$ divides $Z$ or $Y$ then it divides $X$ too.

Assume $p \mid Y$ and $p^2 \nmid Y$. Since $p \mid X$ then
$p$ is coprime to $Z$. Set $Y=p Y_1, X=p X_1$.
Then $Z^{n-2} p Y_1 (p Y_1 + Z)=(p X_1)^n=p^n X_1^n$.
The LHS is divisible by $p$ and is not divisible by $p^2$ and
the RHS is divisible by $p^n$ and we can't equate the exponents
of $p$.

Likewise, assume $p \mid Z$ and $p^2 \nmid Z$. Since $p \mid X$ then
$p$ is coprime to $Y$. Set $Z=p Z_1, X=p X_1$.
Then $p^{n-2} Z_1^{n-2} Y (Y + p Z_1)=(p X_1)^n=p^n X_1^n$.
The LHS is divisible by $p^{n-2}$ and is not divisible by $p^{n-1}$ and
the RHS is divisible by $p^n$ and we can't equate the exponents
of $p$.

> Q2 Is this correct proof that the non-trivial points are with
>   $Y,Z$ powerful integers?

Comment: If $(X,Y,Z)$ was a nontrivial solution, then $x=X/Z,y=Y/Z$ would satisfy $x^n=y(y+1)$. How does the answer to the other question not answer this one?

Comment: @Wojowu Indeed. I am mainly interested in extending the partial results, if this gets closed will move it in the other question.

Comment: What partial results? There are no solutions, what else is there to say?

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, will edit! The other answer assumes FLT and I am interested in elementary proof, not using heavy stuff like FLT and modularity.

Comment: @Wojowu I edited, does it make sense now?

Comment: It makes sense, and you can't prove there are no solutions without FLT - if $a^n+b^n=c^n$ with $a,b,c$ coprime, then $X=b^{n-2}c,Y=a^n,Z=b^n$ is a solution to your equation.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks. Is the converse true:  all points on C_n are on the Fermat curve. By the argument about equating exponents of p in the LHS and RHS Y,Z are n-th powers. This leads to Z_1^(n*(n-2)) Y_1^n (Y_1^n+Z1^n)=X^n. All factors except (Y_1^n+Z1^n) are n-th powers so  it must be n-th power too.

Comment: @Wojowu Your reduction from FLT is slightly wrong: $X=a c b^{n-2}$